# Prove $E\left[^k\right]$= $\frac{r}{p}E\left[(Y-1)^k\right]$ for negative binomial distribution

Tags: probability-distributions

Given $X\sim\text{NB}(r,p)$ and $Y\sim\text{NB}(r+1,p)$, how do I prove the above identity?

Comment: Your hint would be to couple $X$ and $Y$ : make one dependent on the other. This can be done in an obvious manner.

Comment: I thought of equating X=Y-1 but I could not see why P(X=k)=P(Y-1=k) @TeresaLisbon

Comment: That is not correct, right? What you need is  : given $X \sim NB(r,p)$, you need to wait for another success to get $r+1$ successes i.e. $Y$,and each success is given by a geometric random variable independent of $X$. So take $Y = X+G$ where $G$ is a geometric random variable (with probability $p$), and now see what happens.

Comment: Ohhh I see, does that mean I will have to solve for the pmf of the joint probability X+G? @TeresaLisbon

Comment: Exactly. Basically, the idea is that $Y = X+G$ in distribution, therefore $E[Y^k] = E[(X+G)^k]$ for any $k$. This means that you only need to know what the moments of the geometric distribution are, and then use the binomial theorem in the expansion of $(X+G)^k$.

Comment: I see okay thank you for your help! @TeresaLisbon